# Internal Server Error in OAuth for Google

Tags: meteor, oauth, google-account

EDIT: I was able to resolve the original error here when I realized my `ROOT URL` was set to my IP address rather than my domain.  However, I now have a new issue.  My client ID is the same as the original post below.  This works fine in the local app, but in production, the popup flashes for a second and then the login box displays "Internal Server Error".  I can't see any other messages that would explain it.

I am using the `service-configuration` package to load the settings, as follows:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
    { service: "google" },
        {
            $set: {
                clientId: "************",
                loginStyle: "popup",
                secret: "***********"
            }
        }
);
```

If I add `?close` to the end of my Authorized redirect URI, the Google popup comes up with a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error, showing the URI without `?close`.  I think there was an issue resolved [here](https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/issues/109) but it at least shows me that my project in Google is being recognized.

ORIGINAL POST
I am setting up an OAuth 2.0 client ID for `accounts-google` in Meteor and am seeing the following error:

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed:
http://***.***.***.***/_oauth/google
```

My Client ID in Google:

```
Authorized Javascript Origins
http://localhost:3000
http://myApp.com

Authorized redirect URIs
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google
http://myApp.com/_oauth/google
```

I understand I must not be properly pointing the domain to the IP address.  I have already set up an A record and the site works fine in other regards though, so not sure what step I missed.

Comment: any solution for this problem ?

Comment: I never found a solution.