# How to run $ ROOT_URL='https://example.org' meteor command on heroku Server

Tags: meteor, heroku

I have implemented google base authentication in my meteor application but i keep getting a 500 internal server error and a popup splash when i click on login with google button , something similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468374/internal-server-error-in-oauth-for-google)

As a solution try out solution how can i run this command in my heroku server 
($ ROOT_URL='https://example.org' meteor )

Comment: Can you look at the server logs and see what causes the 500 error? Are you wanting to set the ROOT_URL for meteor?

Comment: Hi @Mikkel  the issue was only in production when i looked into meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration collection the document which had google records had a "/n "front of the values with some extra  spaces that was causing the issue